# Prolog: Read list from file

Tags: prolog

I have a text file containing a list like this one:

```
[(3,3,0), (3,5,0), (4,4,1), (5,1,0), (6,6,3)].
```

Is there a built-in Prolog predicate that can load this list from a file?

Or do I have to read the data as plain text and then do the parsing by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate `read/1` does that for you.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I access the numbers in list? It's like unnamed predicates and when i print list i get 3,3,0 for each "node" in list. But i want to acces only 0, and i don't know how to do this. Maybe you know?

Comment: print3rd((_,_,Third)):- write(Third).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so simple open/3 and read/1 does it :) Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: going with open/3, should be read/2, of course... and don't forget close/1 !